# How to WPF slider value make sure the numbers be shown to the thousandths?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, slider

I have `TextBox` of binded `Slider` value and I want make sure the numbers be shown to the thousandths.

How do I get it?

```xml
<Slider x:Name="AOch1" 
        Maximum="20" 
        Minimum="4" 
        Value="4" 
        Width="250" 
        BorderThickness="5" 
        TickPlacement="BottomRight"
        Margin="0 -20 0 0" 
        ValueChanged="AOch1_ValueChanged"/>

<TextBox Width="70" 
         Height="20" 
         Grid.Row="1" 
         Margin="0 0 80 180" 
         x:Name="AO1text"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=AOch1,Path=Value}"/>
```

Comment: You can write a [ValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-convert-bound-data?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Text="{Binding ElementName=AOch1,Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:F3}}"
```